# How to use openweathermap API Key

Tags: python, openweathermap

I'm trying to use Openweathermap for Python with PyOWM, and I have my API key but I've got no idea how to use it in my python program.

I've got no idea what the [Use OpenWeatherMap API page](http://openweathermap.org/appid#use) is trying to say because when I click the "Example of API Call" link, it takes me to a page with nothing but this:

```
{"cod":401, "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}
```

and I can't seem to stay signed in on the previously linked page

Comment: The link on the page doesn't work because the APPID param has a placeholder value. Switch it with your API key

Comment: That's exactly your problem ^^

Comment: @xbonez I changed the placeholder value to my key and it's still giving me the same 401 message. Here's my exact URL that I'm trying to use, http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=524901&APPID=4c6edcf361760cb866b62a719ae83993      I've tried multiple keys that I've generated and none of them are working

Comment: and what do I do with that URL once I get it working?

Comment: @Nexion21 I signed up on that website to try it out. It says that new keys can take 10-60min to start working. Did you generate your key within the last 60min?

Comment: @xbonez I'm fairly certain that the problem I was having is that I can only call the API once every 10 minutes, so when I finally got the link to work, I barely recognized it... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add something like this to your code

```
api_key = "yourkey"
base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
city_name = ("example_city")
complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name
response = requests.get(complete_url)
```

make sure you have requests and json installed and imported.